# Is it safe to mount my USB HDD to /home/partimag to clone partition

Tags: partition, clonezilla

My new laptop is broken and I've connected hdd (500GB) to my old laptop using usb. I want to backup my windows partition (125GB) from old laptop hdd (500GB) using clonezilla but I don't have enough room on /home partition. Is it safe to mount my another external usb hard drive (1TB) to /home/partimag? I have lot of data on that disk.

I want to know what clonezilla will do to /home/partimag directory. Is it safe to mount disk that have lot of data there?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify which partition is on which disk, and which one of the several you mention is the one you want to clone. For something like this it's **essential** you are precise to avoid any possibility of a misunderstanding resulting in you losing data.

Comment: In principle it's safe to mount your USB HDD everywhere you like. Many distributions have pre-made mountpoints in `/mnt/` or `/media`, so I'd use one of those.

Comment: @roaima edited.

Comment: @dirkt yes but I want to know what clonezilla will do to /home/partimag will it just create a file on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the [documentation for Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php), there is even a [worked example](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) showing how it is possible to write a disk (partition) image to a file within the filesystem.

- Initialise Clonezilla, either from the LiveCD or as an installed application
- Choose "Start Clonezilla"
- **Choose "device-image" option**
- Choose "local_dev" option to assign sdb1 as the image home
- Select sdb1 as image repository, then choose "savedisk" option
- Input image name and select source disk
- Clonezilla is saving disk image (sda) to the partition of 2nd disk (sdb1)